# Use a PHP form script from another website on a static website

Tags: php, html, forms, api

so here is my problem :

I have been asked to create a contact form on a CMS called "myshopingonline". The ex developer of this website already added an html contact form submitting the form on a php script (email.php) from his own website (other domaine name, website A sends POST datas to website B's email.php script).

I don't really know this myshopingonline CMS at all so the first thing I thought was using a pluging instead of coding the form. Appearantly, no plugins. Second solution : since I can't code any PHP on the CMS dashboard : create a php file I would add with my ftp client. The thing is I don't have the ftp access (I'll probably go for this solution when I'll have the ftp access).

The people who asked me to make that html form work, were telling me that the form was sending emails to the ex developer. So I was curious : sending POST datas from domain A to domain B and domain B script sending the emails instead of A doing it (a bit like a service no?).

So I tried to create a subdomain on one of my domains just to try out this method that was supposed to work. So, classic, the begining of domain B script is :

```
    if (!isset($_POST['submit'])){
        echo 'ERROR';
...
```

Form from domain A ends by :

```
 <input name="submit" value="submit" type="submit" />
```

And no surprises : I get the ERROR message (tried to see if the form was working when it's on the same domain and it works fine...). So my question is : is it possible to make that work ? Making it work would mean that domain B would "accept" POST datas from A and excecuting the script with those datas.

I guess it's equivalent to building a service or a API ?

In advance, thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, why not.

Consider this example, located on domain A (updated the code and added method="post"):

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="http://domainB.example.com/email.php" method="post">
<input name="data" value="test data" type="text" />
<input name="submit" value="submit" type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

That form would be hosted on domain A and would be executing the php script on domain B. Now, consider that you have this php script on domain B:

```
<?php
  if (!isset($_POST['submit'])){
    echo 'ERROR';
  else
    echo 'POST request received';
?>
```

Now, try accessing the page on the domain A, click the submit button and watch what happens (also note the address in your web browser, which will change too, after you press the 'submit' button).

Comment: I corrected you code : <form action="http://www.testyn.tk" method="POST"> indicating the method because by default it uses GET and it works !! I m really surprised since I ve tried the exact same thing with my script... probably an error somewhere though it did work when I put the script and form on the same domain... Thanks !!